# Batch wise insert in table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have large table and need to move data regularly weekend.

I need batch insert that how can I do.. I tried below code and it goes in loop continuously. PlEASE SUGGEST better fast way.

```
-- CREATE TABLE tmptbl1 (ids int)
--------------------------------------
;WITH q (n) AS (
   SELECT 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT n + 1
   FROM   q
   WHERE  n < 10000
)
INSERT INTO tmptbl1 
SELECT * FROM q
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
--------------------------------------
-- CREATE TABLE tmptbl2 (ids int)

WHILE(1 = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tmptbl2 (ids)
    SELECT TOP 1000 ids FROM tmptbl1
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @skip int = 0
WHILE(1 = 1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tmptbl2 (ids)
    select top 1000 ids from tmptbl1 where ids not in(select top (@skip) ids from tmptbl1)
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
    select @skip=@skip+1000
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I have sql 2008 tag specified while posting this question.

Comment: Amended for sql2008, try it now

Answer (score 0):

You can try SELECT INTO

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Or partition switching for very large tables if you are using MS SQL Server:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I just want to insert records in batch.. lets say I have 10000 records and want to process 1000 rows in each batch to insert.

Comment: You can try paging http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671902/Paging-in-MS-SQL-Server-using-ROW-NUMBER. There is also new functionality in SQL Server 2012 FETCH-OFSET. But why do you want to implement batch processing?